# Reading funny delimited txt file

Tags: pandas

I have a txt file that looks like this. When reading it, it reads it as one column. I have tried to use a lot of different sep=

```
$Eid, X, Y, Z, Mass
  856395   3.4694275e-01  -9.7051837e-02   6.4922004e+00   7.3136240e-03
  856396   3.4694746e-01  -9.7053476e-02   6.5071974e+00   7.3139570e-03
  856397   3.4695095e-01  -9.7054794e-02   6.5221949e+00   7.3139421e-03
  856398   3.4695303e-01  -9.7055703e-02   6.5371923e+00   7.3139500e-03
```

```
df_data = pd.read_csv("ElCEntroid kopi-kopi.txt", skiprows=2, sep="t")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine `t` it not your separator but rather tabulations (`\t`):

you can try:

```
df_data = pd.read_csv('ElCEntroid kopi-kopi.txt',
                      skiprows=1, header=None,
                      sep='\s+'                    # or sep='\t'
                     )
```

output:

```
        0         1         2         3               4
0  856395  0.346943 -0.097052  6.492200   7.3136240e-03
1  856396  0.346947 -0.097053  6.507197   7.3139570e-03
2  856397  0.346951 -0.097055  6.522195   7.3139421e-03
3  856398  0.346953 -0.097056  6.537192   7.3139500e-03
```

Btw, if you're interested in the header, you could also use:

```
df_data = pd.read_csv('ElCEntroid kopi-kopi.txt', sep=",?\s+", engine='python')
```

output:

```
     $Eid         X         Y         Z            Mass
0  856395  0.346943 -0.097052  6.492200   7.3136240e-03
1  856396  0.346947 -0.097053  6.507197   7.3139570e-03
2  856397  0.346951 -0.097055  6.522195   7.3139421e-03
3  856398  0.346953 -0.097056  6.537192   7.3139500e-03
```

Comment: Perfect! Works - another small thing. How do I set the column $Eid as index col with name "ElementId"?

Comment: And how do I remove this: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  return func(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: @AsbjoernLund 1- add `.set_index('$Eid').rename_axis('ElementId')` 2- this is a warning, you can add `engine='python'` as argument to `read_csv`

Answer (score 0):

Is the file a fixed width file?  If so you can use `pd.read_fwf()` instead.  This is really helpful if you know in advance the width of each column.  Im assuming here that Eid, X, Y, Z, Mass have width 8, 16, 16, 16, and 16 respectively, but you can change it if its different.

```
df = pd.read_fwf("ElCEntroid kopi-kopi.txt", skiprows=2, widths=[8, 16, 16, 16, 16])
```